# Need A Way To Apply Formatting To ObjectListView Through A Second Form

Tags: vb.net, filtering, objectlistview

I have a form with an ObjectListView control that is currently full of objects.  I have a public SubRoutine on that same form that applies filtering to the Objects.  When I run the SubRoutine within that form, it applies the filtering correctly and as expected:

```
Public Sub ApplyFiltering() 
    Ticket_Assignee.ValuesChosenForFiltering.Add("John")
    Listview.UpdateColumnFiltering()
End Sub
```

However, if I call that public SubRoutine from another form, the code steps through but the formatting is not applied.

```
Form2.ApplyFiltering()
```

Not even sure if this can be done, but if so would appreciate some advice on where I'm going wrong.
Thanks

Comment: you should instance your forms and consider designing some classes to drive the app

Comment: @Plutonix I normally do, but in this case I don't want to instance the form as I always want to maintain the forms last state when a user changes to it, therefore I simply hide it and display it when appropriate.  I also do use classes, but I'm not sure what you mean in your response.

Comment: proper form instances can use Show/Hide as well; you probably have a scope issue.  A class OTOH might be called when the press the button to Filter or DoSomething rather than form code.  The class, then can then know what to do on what form.  If the class is what created the form reference, it can easily Show it and then fiddle with the control as well (again, rather than form level code).

Comment: @Plutonix I appreciate your feedback.  Could you possibly post some sort of an example or link reference that I could follow to give me a better understanding.  Thanks